# How to make a double have always three decimal points? C++

Tags: c++

I'm coding a program that takes user inputs and get the average of it. I need the average to always have three decimal points.
float didn't work.
some tutorials online advised to use setprecision() and fixed. That won't work because I don't know how long the number is gonna be.

Do you recommend converting the number into a string, get the length, and convert it back to double and use: setprecision(string.length+3)

Thanks

Comment: [Floating points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) don't have decimal digits in [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). Only their output representations have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float ex[] = { 0.12345, 1.2345, 12.345};
    cout << setprecision(3) << fixed;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
        cout << ex[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which gives the following output:

```
0.123
1.235
12.345
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the full precision of double during your calculations, and then display your final result with three decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>  // header file for setprecision()
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double input[4] = {1.000 , 2.0000 , 3.00 , 5.235 };
   double answer = 0 , sum = 0 ;
   int count = 0; 

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
           sum+=input[i];
           count++;
    }

    answer = sum/count;

    cout.precision(3);
    cout << answer << endl;

   return 0;
}
```